# An error occurred during export error on export for Ad Hoc distribution

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an iOS app which I am trying to export for ad hoc distribution everything goes well until I select export option and after selecting "export for all devices" following error pops up.

> An error occurred during export
>   The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Not sure what does that mean, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe internet issue please try once again in some other network. Make sure about firewall too.

Comment: Internet is working perfect and tried it few times

Comment: Any error code.

Comment: Nothing all what I got have posted in quote

Comment: What are you using for distribution? Xcode or Application Loader.

Comment: Xcode 8.0 not application loader

Comment: Try disabling bitcode and use application loader.

Comment: Tried disabling and it works but can that be a real solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disable the BitCode from your project and try to build it again.

What does the ENABLE_BITCODE actually do, will it be a non-optional requirement in the future?

When you build your project, Xcode invokes clang for Objective-C targets and swift/swiftc for Swift targets. Both of these compilers compile the app to an intermediate representation (IR), one of these IRs is bitcode. From this IR, a program called LLVM takes over and creates the binaries needed for x86 32 and 64 bit modes (for the simulator) and arm6/arm7/arm7s/arm64 (for the device). Normally, all of these different binaries are lumped together in a single file called a fat binary.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a good solution but I will mark it as an answer coz that solved the issue.